# Dataframe to nested dictionary with column names as keys

Tags: python, pandas

```
index    pair       number      amount
0        158_151    0000002732  104
```

What I want is:

{'158_151': {'number': 0000002732, 'amount': 104} ...

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking to the [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html?highlight=to_dict#pandas.DataFrame.to_dict) method:

```py
df.set_index("pair").to_dict("index")
{'158_151': {'number': '000000002732', 'amount': 104}}
```

`to_dict` accept different argument for the output format. Read the doc in order to provide the correct output for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Number column has the problem and I think it should be string.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'pair': ["158_151"],
        'number': ["0000002732"],
        'amount':[104]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.set_index('pair').to_dict("index")
print(df)
```

Output: `{'158_151': {'number': "0000002732", 'amount': 104}}`